# re.sub method not working with '$' pattern

Tags: python

Am trying to replace 'and' at the end of the string with re.sub method. But either all the 'and' are getting changed or nothing is getting changed. I need to replace and only at the end.

```
fvalue = "$filter = Name eq 'abc' and Address eq 'xyz' and "
regex = r'(and\$)'
f_value = re.sub(regex,'',fvalue)
print(fvalue)
```

Output

```
$filter = Name eq 'abc' and Address eq 'xyz' and
```

Comment: You should not escape it with a backslash. Otherwise it will be matched as a literal $

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems with your code. First, you're printing the input, not the output. But also, you're escaping the `$` as pointed out in the comments, and you have whitespace after the "and" in the input but before the end of the string, so `(and$)` will not match either.

Try something like this:

```
fvalue = "$filter = Name eq 'abc' and Address eq 'xyz' and "
regex = r'and\s*$'
f_value = re.sub(regex,'',fvalue)
print(f_value)
```

I removed the capture group, since you're not using it, unescaped the `$` anchor, and inserted possible whitespace (`\s*`).

And finally, print the result `f_value` instead of the input `fvalue`.